# Comparing data in two columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, compare, vlookup, accounting

The data

[image]

[image]

I need a formula to find out if column 1 has a pair in column 2.

The aim is to find the value that does not have a pair.

I have 4,333 rows of data and doing it manually would take me hours.

I tried

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$5,1,0)
```

but somehow it did not work... :(

Comment: Use `MATCH()` function.

Comment: If you have 4333 rows it shouldn't be `B2:B5` (4 rows). Probably you need `=VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$4233,1,0)`, or since you're interested in the non-matching: `=ISNA(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$4233,0))`

Comment: @P.b surely it should be $B$2:$B$4333 otherwise you miss the last 100 rows?

Comment: Ah, I thought it was 4233, but I see I got that wrong. It should be up to 4333 indeed.

Comment: @P.b Ups! It should be 4334 if the range starts from B2.

Comment: Well to the last row containing data, but I think that was clear

Comment: @P.b my issue is not with how many rows i selected, it simply says there is a problem with the formula :(

Comment: Are you using `;`-separator maybe? `=VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$4333;1;0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best formula helps you is a single-cell formula

```
[C1]=XMATCH(A1:Axxxxx,B1:Byyyyy)
```

where xxxxx - the last row in `A`, yyyyy - the last row in `B`.

[image]

In this solution, for each element in the first column, XMATCH displays the matched element from the second column or `#N/A` if no match found.

Comment: i tried but it says the same thing as with the other formulas : "there is a problem with this formula" the formula i put: =XMATCH(J2:J4333;K2:K4333) it sees the first selected column but not the second

Comment: Please change the semicolon to the comma, which is the list separator in your system as per the qustion.

Comment: It did something!! :)) so the numbers it lists indicate how many pairs there are to a certain number ?  or what do they mean?